# How to use Vertica AVG [Analytic]

Tags: sql, average, vertica

I have a Vertica table like the following example:

[image: table data example]

I would like to write SQL query, that calculates the "avg" rate for each site but shell calculates only devices that their rate is higher than site avg rate.

so the result for my query should be

[image: excpected result]

since the average rate for site 1 is 3 so we need to calculate only 4 and 5 and the result is 4.5.
since the average rate for site 2 is 8 so we need to calculate only 8 and 9 and the result is 8.5.

what is the query for this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want:

```
select site, avg(rate)
from (select t.*, avg(t.rate) over (partition by t.site) as avg_rate
      from t
     ) t
where rate > avg_rate
group by site;
```

To use a window function result in a `where` clause, you need a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Gordon's answer is completely correct. Just for thoroughness' sake. Another way you can write the query is with the `with` clause.

```sql
WITH avg_part AS (
        SELECT t.*, AVG(t.rate) OVER(PARTITION BY t.site) as avg_rate
        FROM t
)
SELECT site, avg(rate)
FROM avg_part
WHERE rate > avg_rate
GROUP BY site;
```